# Which Windows IDE to write, execute and debug single-file C# programs?

Tags: c#, windows, ide

I use Visual Studio 2010 for C# development. But, there are many times during the day when I need to quickly try out a small bit of C# code to experiment or learn something new. I can write this as a **fully functional C# program in a single file**. Now, I can use Visual Studio for writing/editing this C# files, but it does not support execution or debugging (breakpoint, watch variables) unless I create a solution for it.

I would like to have the ability to **create**, **edit**, **execute** (and hopefully **debug**) single C# files, without having to go through the pains of creating a VS solution everytime I need to try something. **Is there a simple C# IDE on Windows in which I can do this?**

The IDE should not create any project/solution files. That way I can have a directory of C# files, each of which is a full C# program and each of which I can open to read, edit and execute with this IDE anytime I want.

Comment: For this purpose, I have a single project (named "Scratch") with a single file in it.  I keep it open in Visual Studio all the time and use it for testing code snippets.

Comment: James: I was actually doing this until a while ago. Later, I had to keep around many standalone C# files and this trick fails for that.

Comment: @James, I do the same thing. Although I also use git so that I can commit and go back to everything I have tried.

Answer (score 9):

**[LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/)** can execute expressions, statements, or small programs that could be a single file in size (also see [this](http://www.linqpad.net/CodeSnippetIDE.aspx) page). It does not create projects/solution files just as you are seeking. Just open, code, and save if you like. I use the free version to test code I post on this site.

It supports .Net 4.0 and has some other nice features, such as not needing to explicitly specify using statements. The program is smart enough to know which ones you need.

Answer (score 4):

Try [Snippet Compiler](http://www.sliver.com/dotnet/SnippetCompiler/)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In the next release of C# and Visual Studio, one of the new features is [Project Roslyn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/roslyn), a compiler-as-a-service implementation.  The upshot is that this enables is scripting in C#, with .csx files.  The Visual Studio blog has a lot more information on .csx files [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2011/10/19/introducing-the-microsoft-roslyn-ctp.aspx).

I myself haven't played with .csx files much, but they seem similar to .fsx files for scripting F#, in that you take the code that you would normally place inside a method (in F#, a function) and place it at top-level, and can use the hash to introduce compiler directives (e.g. #r to reference a DLL).